# How to rename multiple files in a directory in some pattern in Linux?

Tags: linux, shell, ls

I have a directory which has files with random names. What I want to do is rename the files with file1, file2 and so on.The lexicographically smaller file name should be numbered with smaller number. How can I do that?

Comment: Also look at `pyrenamer`. Depending on your distro, it may be in your standard repositories.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple bash script should do it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

count=0
for i in *; do
    mv "${i}" file${count}.`echo "${i}" | awk -F. '{print $2}'`
    ((++count))
done
```

To help with a line-by-line explanation:

1. Location of the bash shell this is executing under, determined by your environmental variable.
2. Set the variable "count" to 0
3. Creates a for-loop, iterating over the output of the command `ls` (sorted alphabetically by default).
4. Moves (i.e. renames) the file "i" (current one in the loop) to `file#.ext`.  The "#" is the current number in "count" and the stuff past the "." is a quick way to get the current file extension (so this could work in a folder of various file extensions).
5. Increment the counter variable

loop, loop, loop

6. done!

**Note**:

1. This executes in whatever directory you are executing it from.  So as a script, you'd want to add a command line argument.  Instead I would open a terminal, navigate to the directory to do this on, and execute the following (exactly):

   ```
   for i in *; do mv "${i}" "file${count}".`echo "${i}" | 
     awk -F. '{print $2}'`; ((++count)); done
   ```
2. This is assuming that you only have file names such as "file.txt" not "this.is.a.file.txt"

Comment: Two things: Use `*` instead of `\`ls\``, and quote `${i}`: `"${i}"`.

Comment: As @ChristofferHammarström says, use `*` not `ls`, because your code will handle files with spaces incorrectly, and because the output from `ls` is not guaranteed always to be the same on different systems. Also quote your use of the variables, as `"${i}"` and `"${2}"`, because multiple, leading and trailing spaces will be affected. A minor point: In the calculation, you can omit the parameter-substitution, as `count=$(( count + 1 ))` or, even better, just use `(( ++count ))` by itself.

Comment: @PaddyLandau - Thanks for the tips (and explanation)!  Updated.

Comment: Your script assumes all files have extensions which is not necessarily true.

Comment: @terdon - Good point, in which case the OP can simply drop everything between `${count}` and the following `;` (exclusive).

Comment: `count=((++count))` is a syntax error in bash. Just use `((++count))` on its own. Moreover, your renaming starts with number `0`, not `1` as wanted by the OP.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf - Updated with the count, thanks.  As for the other item - they can simply adjust the count to start at 1.

Comment: The code in "Note" also needs changing to quote the variables (`"${i}"` and `${2}"`). Yet another point, which I missed the first time around, is that the subprocess also needs to be quoted for exactly the same reasons: `mv "${i}" file${count}."$( echo "${i}" | awk -F. '{print $2}' )"` (I changed the back-ticks to `$(…)` because of formatting restrictions).

Comment: No need for `awk` here, instead you could just use `mv "$i" file${count}."${i##*.}"` and keep everything in bash. This still breaks on files without extensions, though, but in a different way.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
#enter the path to the folder: relative or absolute
direc = raw_input('Enter the path to directory: ')
os.chdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),direc))
files = os.listdir('.')
def func(x):
    return map(str.lower,os.path.splitext(x))
files.sort(key = func)
for i,x in enumerate(files, 1):
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(x)
    os.rename(x, 'file{}{}'.format(i,ext))
```

Comment: I would suggest making your script respect extensions (an easy update), I'll +1 when you do that since otherwise their files may be like "wtf mate?"

Comment: @nerdwaller solution updated.

Answer (score 2):

A [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) possibility (similar to nerdwaller's solution, but without subshells and forks to [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)):

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob

count=0
for i in *; do
    mv -nv -- "$i" "file$((++count))"
done
```

Switches for `mv`:

- `-n` for no clobber: won't overwrite an otherwise existing file. Remove it if you actually want to overwrite files (might not be available depending on your version of `mv`),
- `-v` for verbose: tell what it's doing. Highly optional (but I like to have these lines on my terminal to impress my colleagues),
- `--` for end of options: without this, and if a filename starts with a hyphen, that would confuse `mv` as it would try to interpret it as an option. Might not be available depending on your version of `mv`. Use it if available!

I'm also using the shell optional behavior `nullglob` so that if there are no files, then you won't get any errors (the loop will not get executed as `*` would expand to nothing in this case).

---

If you need to handle extensions too (as in nerdwaller's version), you don't need [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), it can all be done in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob

count=0
for i in *; do
    mv -nv -- "$i" "file$((++count)).${i##*.}"
done
```

---

Observe that the numbering will not have any leading zeros, so that you'll get files named so:

```
file1
file2
...
file10
file11
...
```

and this might screw up the order of the files in listings. If you need leading zeros too:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob

files=( * )

lz=0
for ((n=${#files[@]};n;n/=10)); do ((++lz)); done

count=0
for i in "${files[@]}"; do
    printf -v n "%0${lz}d" $((++count))
    mv -nv -- "$i" "file$n"
done
```

And if you want it to keep the original file's extension, replace the line

```
mv -nv -- "$i" "file$n"
```

with

```
mv -nv -- "$i" "file$n.${i##*.}"
```

---

*Caveats*.

- Because this uses [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) globbing, it might be quite slow if you have a huge number of files in your directory (globbing can take some time).
- This will rename everything, including directories, but not hidden files.

*Cures*.

- I don't have any solutions regarding speed in case of huge number of files in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash).
- If you need to discard directories from this renaming procedure, and only rename files, add `[[ -f $i ]] || continue` just after the `for i in *; do` statement.
- If you need to also rename hidden files, add `shopt -s dotglob` just after the `shopt -s nullglob` statement.

---

If you read down to here, I guess you'll be able to craft something that matches your very own need from the examples I gave you, hopefully using good [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) practice (provided you choose to solve your problem using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) of course).

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to implement the same when I was a student and was studying the Linux Shell Scripts.
then I created the below script.. Have a look..
https://github.com/rushyang/GTU-OS-Bash-Scripts/blob/master/Working/System%20Scripts/final_rename_updated.sh